# Регулярным выражением удалить ссылки по списку из массива

Tags: массивы, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть список ссылок из котрогого нужно удалить некоторые из них.
список удаляемых ссылок хранится в массиве.

Пробовал по всякому никак не получается, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>

<script>
function start() {
var toremove = document.querySelector('.TgListPosts'); // ... 
var myArray = ['зита', 'Вася', 'hello']; // массив со словами для замены

if (toremove) {

  for (var i = 0, l = myArray.length; i < l; i++) {

console.log('Found: ' + myArray.length);
console.log('Found: ' + myArray[i]);

toremove.innerHTML = toremove.innerHTML.replace('/<a.*?'+myArray[i]+'<\/a>/gi','');

  }
}
}
window.onload=start; // запускаем функцию start при загрузке окна
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="777">
<p>Не изменяемый пример: 
<a href="#1" class="linkTagPost">Вася</a>
<a href="#2" class="linkTagPost">Дима</a>
<a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Лена</a>
<a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Ита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Вита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Зита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Гита</a>
<a href="#5" class="linkTagPost">Витя</a>
<a href="#6" class="linkTagPost">Митя</a>
</div>

<div class="TgListPosts"> 
<p>Изменяемый пример 01: 
<a href="#1" class="linkTagPost">Вася</a>
<a href="#2" class="linkTagPost">Дима</a>
<a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Лена</a>
<a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Ита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Вита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Зита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Гита</a>
<a href="#5" class="linkTagPost">Витя</a>
<a href="#6" class="linkTagPost">Митя</a>
<p>Изменяемый пример 02: 
<a href="#1" class="linkTagPost">Вася</a>
<a href="#2" class="linkTagPost">Дима</a>
<a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Лена</a>
<a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Ита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Вита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Зита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Гита</a>
<a href="#5" class="linkTagPost">Витя</a>
<a href="#6" class="linkTagPost">Митя</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Прочитал. Ничего не понял. Что надо искать, почему надо именно их искать, на что конкретно заменять и пр

Comment: На странице есть меню из ссылок с именами. 
Нужно удалить некотрые ссылки из страницы. Ссылки для удаления ищутся по словам в тексте ссылок. Список слов для поиска сохранен в массиве.

Да вы верно написали

Comment: Давай я за тебя попробую сформулировать вопрос: нужно удалить со страницы ссылку (весь тег `a`), если в его тексте встречается текст из массива. Так?

Comment: Да верно.
Я пытался понять в чем дело но консоль не выдает ошибок. я не могу понять что я делаю не так

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
toremove.innerHTML = toremove.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('/<a.*?'+myArray[i]+'<\/a>/gi'),'');
```

Comment: Попробовал не помогло, возможно я допустил ошибку где то в другом месте. консоль ошибок не выдает, отчего совсем загадка.

Answer (score 0):

Без регуярок:

```js
function start() {
  //var toremove = document.querySelector('.TgListPosts'); // ...
  
  
  let linkPosts =  document.querySelectorAll('.TgListPosts .linkTagPost');
  var myArray = ['зита', 'Вася', 'hello']; // массив со словами для замены
  let arrLowerCased = myArray.map(element => element.toLowerCase());

  linkPosts.forEach((el) => {
      if (arrLowerCased.includes(el.textContent.toLowerCase()))
          el.remove();        
  });
}

window.onload = start; // запускаем функцию start при загрузке окна
```

```html
<div class="777">
  <p>Не изменяемый пример:</p>
    <a href="#1" class="linkTagPost">Вася</a>
    <a href="#2" class="linkTagPost">Дима</a>
    <a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Лена</a>
    <a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Ита</a>
    <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Вита</a>
    <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Зита</a>
    <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Гита</a>
    <a href="#5" class="linkTagPost">Витя</a>
    <a href="#6" class="linkTagPost">Митя</a>
</div>

<div class="TgListPosts">
  <p>Изменяемый пример 01:</p>
    <a href="#1" class="linkTagPost">Вася</a>
    <a href="#2" class="linkTagPost">Дима</a>
    <a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Лена</a>
    <a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Ита</a>
    <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Вита</a>
    <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Зита</a>
    <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Гита</a>
    <a href="#5" class="linkTagPost">Витя</a>
    <a href="#6" class="linkTagPost">Митя</a>
    <p>Изменяемый пример 02:</p>
      <a href="#1" class="linkTagPost">Вася</a>
      <a href="#2" class="linkTagPost">Дима</a>
      <a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Лена</a>
      <a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Ита</a>
      <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Вита</a>
      <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Зита</a>
      <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Гита</a>
      <a href="#5" class="linkTagPost">Витя</a>
      <a href="#6" class="linkTagPost">Митя</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Алексей спасибо вам! Хороший вариант. Я надеюсь что всетаки смогу понять что в первом примере не так.

Comment: Не стоит понимать. Потому что теги никогда не стоит парсить регуляркой. Никогда.........а не так может быть например то, что нет закрывающего тега `p` и он как-то всё портит......в целом....есть отладка для того, чтобы пробегаться по каждой строке кода.....

Comment: @Сергей, не работает, так как регулярное выражение не верно форматировано, попробуйте `regex = new RegExp(\`<a.*?${myArray[i]}<\/a>\`, 'gi');`

Answer (score 0):

Регулярные выражения содержащих в себе переменные лучше собирать с использованием конструктора.
Более подробнее ниже:

```js
foo = 'green free';

//литеральная запись
reg = /e{2}/g;
console.log('Литеральная запись(ЛЗ): ' +foo.replace(reg,''));
//true

//литеральная запись в одинарных кавычках
reg = '/e{2}/g';
console.log('ЛЗ с \': ' +foo.replace(reg,''));
//false

//литеральная запись в двойных кавычка
reg = "/e{2}/g";
console.log('ЛЗ c ": ' +foo.replace(reg,''));
//false

a = 'e';
//литеральная запись с подстановкой переменной
reg = `/${a}{2}/g`;
console.log('ЛЗ с переменной: ' +foo.replace(reg,''));
//false

//Конструктор с литеральной записью
reg = new RegExp (`/${a}{2}/g`);
console.log('Конструктор с ЛЗ: ' +foo.replace(reg,''));
//false

//конструктор с переменной
reg = new RegExp (`${a}{2}`,'g');
console.log('конструктор: ' + foo.replace(reg,''))
//true
```

```js
let a = 'Дима';
let docs = document.querySelector('.TgListPosts');
reg = new RegExp(`<a.*?${a}<\/a>`, 'gi');
docs.innerHTML = docs.innerHTML.replace(reg,'');

let b = 'витя';
let docs2 = document.querySelector('.TgListPostsTwo');
docs2.innerHTML = docs2.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(`<a.*?${b}<\/a>`, 'gi'),'');
```

```html
<div class="TgListPosts">
    <a href="#1" class="linkTagPost">Вася</a>
    <a href="#2" class="linkTagPost">Дима</a>
    <a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Лена</a>
    <a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Ита</a>
    <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Вита</a>
    <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Зита</a>
    <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Гита</a>
    <a href="#5" class="linkTagPost">Витя</a>
    <a href="#6" class="linkTagPost">Митя</a>
</div>

<div class="TgListPostsTwo">
    <a href="#1" class="linkTagPost">Вася</a>
    <a href="#2" class="linkTagPost">Дима</a>
    <a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Лена</a>
    <a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Ита</a>
    <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Вита</a>
    <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Зита</a>
    <a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Гита</a>
    <a href="#5" class="linkTagPost">Витя</a>
    <a href="#6" class="linkTagPost">Митя</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем кто откликнулся, с вашей помощью я узнал новые возможности решения. Я смог победить теперь код работает, првда только с такими кавычками.

```
new RegExp (`<a.*?>${myArray[i]}<\/a>`, `gi`);
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>

<script>
function start() {
var toremove = document.querySelector('.TgListPosts');
var myArray = ['31527', 'ита', 'Вася', 'hello'];

    if (toremove) {
        for (var i = 0, l = myArray.length; i < l; i++) {
        reg = new RegExp (`<a.*?>${myArray[i]}<\/a>`, `gi`);

            toremove.innerHTML = toremove.innerHTML.replace(reg, '');
            console.log('Test: ' + reg);
        }
    }
}
window.onload=start;
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="777">
<p>Не изменяемый пример: 
<a href="#1" class="linkTagPost">Вася</a>
<a href="#2" class="linkTagPost">Дима</a>
<a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Лена</a>
<a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Ита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Вита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Зита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Гита</a>
<a href="#5" class="linkTagPost">Витя</a>
<a href="#6" class="linkTagPost">Митя</a>
</div>

<div class="TgListPosts"> 
<p>Изменяемый пример 01: 
<a href="#1" class="linkTagPost">Вася</a>
<a href="#2" class="linkTagPost">Дима</a>
<a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Лена</a>
<a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Ита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Вита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Зита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Гита</a>
<a href="#5" class="linkTagPost">Витя</a>
<a href="#6" class="linkTagPost">Митя</a>
<p>Изменяемый пример 02: 
<a href="#1" class="linkTagPost">Вася</a>
<a href="#2" class="linkTagPost">Дима</a>
<a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Лена</a>
<a href="#3" class="linkTagPost">Ита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Вита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Зита</a>
<a href="#4" class="linkTagPost">Гита</a>
<a href="#5" class="linkTagPost">Витя</a>
<a href="#6" class="linkTagPost">Митя</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```